# getting data from dialog window to main thread

Tags: android, asynchronous, dialog

Okay, I am using pro android 3 book as reference and implemented modal dialog box exactly the way stated in the book. However, I am having hard time getting string from textedit entered in the dialog box to main (calling) thread which calls the dialog box.

FIrst, book tells to implement independent class for implementing the  android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener. In this case the text will not received by main thread as process is asynchronous which is what book tells.

And it tells that the solution is the calling activity will directly implement the callback in android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener which will solve the issue of premature update of string in the main thread. That is main thread will receive the return string only after dialog box is closed.

So I re-architected my application but still it is not working. The main thread is returning the string as 'NULL immediately before the submit button is clicked. Can anyone explain what else I have to do? Thanks